# Join tables based on a column without creating records for every combination

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-3.5

I have two tables as follows:

```
Customer | Product
------------------
    A    |   Car
    A    |  Bike
    A    |  Boat
    B    |   Foo
    B    |   Bar

Customer | Friends
------------------
    A    |   John
    A    |  Andrew
    B    |   Baz
```

For each customer I want to display a list of products purchased, and a list of friends like this:

```
Customer   Products    Friends
------------------------------
A       - Car       - John
        - Bike      - Andrew
        - Boat
------------------------------
B       - Foo       - Baz
        - Bar
```

If I use a normal `JOIN` then I get a list of friends for *every* separate product. I just want the two lists once.

The output lists with '-' need not be table cells, they can be `<ul>`s.

How can I achieve this? I would like to bind to ASP.net GridView. Should I try to do it all in one query, or use multiple queries and somehow add them both to the same Grid?

---

Each row actually forms part of a long report. Essentially each row of the report contains Customer ID, a bunch of other fields which match one-to-one with Customer ID, then the two lists for each Customer ID I described. Perhaps I can use a separate query for each list, then manually add each list to the grid on RowDataBound or similar?

Comment: What's the rule behind ordering the rows exactly that way? E.g. why `John` first, `Andrew` second, and not vice versa?

Comment: You just want to simply concatenate all the products and all the friends separating them with EOLs, right?

Comment: Why are Car and John in the same row? What rule(s) guide this selection?

Comment: Car and John have nothing to do with each other, that's the point. I've added a second customer to make it clearer what I mean. I just want a list of all products, and a list of all friends for each customer. The ordering within the output columns doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong tool for the job. SQL is oriented around result sets, which consist of rows. The values of the columns within each row are meant to be connected with each other (to represent one fact or set of facts).

Comment: Because of the implied `null`s the ordering (and matching) is crucial. Why should there be a Car/John row, and not a Car/Andrew row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How can I achieve the result I want then? Can I use two separate queries, and somehow merge the results into one Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 separate queries since you just want the list of data in 2 tables (with same where condition)

What SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I want to output to a single GridView, so I think I need it all in one query.

Comment: actually you need to have them in same datasource, and you can build a dataset manually merging data from more queries.. anyway there may be some trick using subqueries and rownumbers to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I feel dirty having written this. It's ugly code, because this is *not* how SQL should be used. It doesn't give the exact results asked for, but that's because the matching of friends and products is arbitrary anyway, so I've imposed my own ordering:

```
;with OrderedProducts as (
    select Customer,Product,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Product) rn
    from @Products
), OrderedFriends as (
    select Customer,Friend,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Friend) rn
    from @Friends
)
select
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(op.rn,ofr.rn) = 1 THEN COALESCE(op.Customer,ofr.Customer) END,
    op.Product,
    ofr.Friend
from
    OrderedProducts op
        full outer join
    OrderedFriends ofr
        on
            op.Customer = ofr.Customer and
            op.rn = ofr.rn
order by COALESCE(op.Customer,ofr.Customer),COALESCE(op.rn,ofr.rn)
```

Gives the result:

```
     Product Friend
---- ------- ------
A    Bike    Andrew
NULL Boat    John
NULL Car     NULL
B    Bar     Baz
NULL Foo     NULL
```

Basically, since you don't seem to have one, I made up my own rule for when two rows match between these two tables - that the rows should be numbered alphabetically within each customer, and then used those row numbers to create unique matches between the tables.

The `COALESCE` mucking about is required to deal with customers with friends and no products, or products and no friends. The `CASE` was the only way I could fathom to only have the customer name appear on one row.

---

And this is how I set up the sample data:

```
declare @Products table (
    Customer char(1) not null,
    Product varchar(4) not null
)
insert into @Products (Customer , Product) values
(    'A'    ,   'Car'),
(    'A'    ,  'Bike'),
(    'A'    ,  'Boat'),
(    'B'    ,   'Foo'),
(    'B'    ,   'Bar')

declare @Friends table (
    Customer char(1) not null,
    Friend varchar(6) not null
)
insert into @Friends (Customer , Friend) values
(    'A'    ,   'John'),
(    'A'    ,  'Andrew'),
(    'B'    ,   'Baz')
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree it feels like an abuse of SQL - can you think of a better solution to achieve what I want (perhaps without using GridView)?

Comment: @Andrew - yes, I think avoiding using the GridView in the first place is a good start. But then this becomes more about UI design than data access. Typically for this sort of thing, I'd expect a top-level where the customer is selected, and based on the customer selection, two independent grids/lists/whatever to be populated with friends and products - making clear *in the UI* that there's no correlation between Andrew and Bike.

Comment: Each row actually forms part of a long report. Essentially each row of the report contains Customer ID, a bunch of other fields which match one-to-one with Customer ID, then the two lists for each Customer ID I described. Perhaps I can use a separate query for each list, then manually add each list to the grid on `RowDataBound` or similar?

Comment: @Andrew: Since a Product and a Friend associated with the same Customer are not related to each other, their respective lists should probably be produced in the form of *sub*-reports, if your reporting tool of choice supports such a thing.

Comment: @Damien: I must confess that even though I've written more or less the same query, I don't feel dirty (or maybe not as dirty as you do). In my job, sometimes you have to come up with a quick-and-drity solution before you have time to plan and think everything out, and queries like this do help a lot at times. Thus one gets used to feeling dirty, I guess. :)

Comment: @AndriyM The specification I have been given has them in the same row in a single report, unfortunately I can't change it.

Comment: @Andrew: Well, that doesn't necessarily tell me that sub-reports are out of question. You could (I would try to) accommodate them so as to achieve the desired look of the entire thing. But you know your situation better, of course, and I can imagine that sometimes a better, cleverer solution has to be put aside, at least for the time being.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm sure that the result is correct(as far as possible), but i wonder if it's good practise to insert sample data in another order than it would be expected to prevent _accidently_ correct results.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I'm not sure I understand your point. The sample data is from the OPs question (just re-written as actual inserts), and the results *are* in a different order than the OPs "expected" results, to highlight that some ordering decision has to be made.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: my question was a bit offtopic. Sometimes i get the correct result just because i've inserted the (sample-)data in the desired order, so the query was inccorect but the result was correct. I wouldn't call me an experienced DBA, therefore i've asked you if it could help to prevent such seemingly "correct" result by changing the insert order(you haven't done above).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Um... Re-read the sample data and the result I give (in the middle of my answer) - the result isn't in the same order as the inserts (Andrew appears before John, Bike before Car)

Comment: I'm sure your sql is correct even if you'd have inserted the sample-data in another order than requested. I've wondered if it would be helpful (for me, in general) to force another order when inserting sample data to prevent seemingly correct result which actually are incorrect. But i think my question is pointless since i can answer it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

(This is a large comment)

The result set you gave in the question have three rows:

```
 Customer   Products    Friends
 ------------------------------
 A        - Car       - John
 <NULL>   - Bike      - Andrew
 <NULL>   - Boat      - <NULL>
```

As SQL is not procedural, but set based, this is functionally equivalent to

```
 Customer   Products    Friends
 ------------------------------
 <NULL>   - Boat      - <NULL>
 <NULL>   - Bike      - Andrew
 A        - Car       - John
```

which does not make sense (even less with the two person example).

What you basically want is for each person to get a list of products, and a list of cars, and display that in a single grid.

- But how should it be determined which product "matches" each friend, as they will be in a same row?
- What happens to the empty values if there is a page break in the grid in a middle of a friend listing?
- How should the rows be sorted vis-a-vis the empty values?

In this case I think you are better off if you just get all the data from the database to the server, and do the construction of the GridView's data source with VB.NET.

Comment: You're right that Products and Friends have nothing to do with each other and are really separate queries. The problem is I need to display it all together and I can't find a straightforward way to put two queries into a GridView.

Comment: Take a look at the [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) class ([this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/basic-reporting/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs) is an OK starting tutorial). I'll try to work up an example for your case, but I make no promises :)